# Is Possible to connect Azure SQL managed Instance from Azure SQL DB?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance

Is Possible to connect Azure SQL managed Instance from Azure SQL DB? By design, Azure SQL database is PaaS model with public end point only and Managed Instance has got only private end point. So how to connect the both?
We need to access (Read) few tables in Azure SQL MI from SQL DB using Elastic Query.

Comment: Take a look at [Cross-Database Queries in Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/)

Answer (score 1):

> Is Possible to connect Azure SQL managed Instance from Azure SQL DB?

No, because "Azure SQL [has only a] public end point only and Managed Instance has got only private end point."  You can use Linked Server to connect from Managed Instance to Azure SQL Database.  Or you can use [Replciation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/replication-with-sql-database-managed-instance) to copy the tables from Managed Instance to SQL Database.